# What is the meaning of 'sup' in this equation

Tags: notation

What is the meaning of 'sup' in this equation: $$s(n)= \frac1n\sup_{k\ge0}T^{(k)}(n)$$

The equation is from [this paper](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Lagarias3-23.pdf) on the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: [Supremum](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi24tf5xrzPAhVJHGMKHUJkDqIQFggzMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmathworld.wolfram.com%2FSupremum.html&usg=AFQjCNEGf1ZSvMM2D7617pk0VlBIpziYLA)?

Comment: $\sup$ is always the supremum. 

So in this case you have to consider the set of real numbers $ \{ T^{(0)}(n), T^{(1)}(n), T^{(2)}(n), \cdots \} $ and consider it's least upper bound

Comment: $\sup A_n$ where $A_n=\{T^{(k)}(n)\mid k\geqslant0\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the set $\{T^{(k)}(n):k=0,1,2,\ldots\}.$ Then, $\sup_{k\ge0}T^{(k)}(n)$ is exactly $\sup\{T^{(k)}(n):k=0,1,2,\ldots\}.$ The supremum $\sup A$, where $A$ is a subset of an ordered set $E$, is an element of $E$ such that $x\le \sup A$ for all $x\in A$ and if $b < \sup A$ then there is some $x\in A$ such that $b < x$.

In other words, $\sup A$ is an upper bound of $A$ and it is the smallest upper bound of $A$.